# parse.com Reference Error: user is not defined

Tags: javascript, database, templates, parse-platform

I found this really cool site called http://parse.com. It is an online database (amongst many other things). Definitely check it out. Anyway, I believe I am one step away from figuring out how to use Parse.User, and render the objects email in an ejs template. I have it so that I can create and store users on parse.com - but I dont think that my template is recognizing the "user" variable I created. Here is my code and error:

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signupform").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();

        Parse.initialize("O3LAmHCCGmMWBRuPEt4cXWP5ChQMjeruyOkMN7m1", "AIyuUVnGYbyQrWaYns7TL3XpmjPb1FDeplQ76DgG");

        var user = new Parse.User(); 
        user.setUsername($('#username').val());
        user.setEmail($('#email').val());
        user.setPassword($('#pw').val());

        user.signUp();

        var html = new EJS({url: 'templates/usershow.ejs'}).render(user);
        var content = document.getElementById('listuser');
        content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + html;
        $("#signupform").remove();   
    });
});
```

templates/usershow.ejs

```
<li><%= user.getEmail() %></li>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>it IT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css" />
  <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
  <script src="application.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ejs_production.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.7.min.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>it IT</h1>
    <div id="signup">
        <form id="signupform">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="sign up">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="signin"></div>
    <div id="showuser">
        <h2>Username - Email</h2>
        <ul id="listuser"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get in firebug(after a successful post to the parse.com database) is:

`ReferenceError: user is not defined`

The line in question seems to be the `var html = new EJS({url: 'templates/usershow.ejs'}).render(user);` line. I'm not sure if the render function can recognize a Parse.User object? Maybe a problem using ejs with Parse.User?

**UPDATE**

In response to the comment below, I changed my code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signupform").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();

        Parse.initialize("O3LAmHCCGmMWBRuPEt4cXWP5ChQMjeruyOkMN7m1", "AIyuUVnGYbyQrWaYns7TL3XpmjPb1FDeplQ76DgG");

        var user = new Parse.User(); 
        user.setUsername($('#username').val());
        user.setEmail($('#email').val());
        user.setPassword($('#pw').val());

        user.signUp(null, {
            success: function (user) {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                var html = new EJS({url: 'templates/usershow.ejs'}).render(user);
                var content = document.getElementById('listuser');
                content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + html;
                $("#signupform").remove();   
            },
            error: function (user, error) {
                // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);                        
            }
        });
    });
});
```

While I think this corrected a problem with my code...I am still getting the same error, stated above.

Again, I'm coming back to this line `var html = new EJS({url: 'templates/usershow.ejs'}).render(user);` as the culprit...just because the user object is a Parse.User object and not just a regular object?

Answer (score 0):

The call you are making here is asynchronous, you will need to write your code in the success block of the parse call, so it will be executed once the reply from parse is back to your app.

```
    var user = new Parse.User(); 
    user.setUsername($('#username').val());
    user.setEmail($('#email').val());
    user.setPassword($('#pw').val());

            newUser.signUp(null, {
                success: function (user) {
                    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                    var html = new EJS({url: 'templates/usershow.ejs'}).render(user);
                    var content = document.getElementById('listuser');
                    content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + html;
                    $("#signupform").remove();   
                },
                error: function (user, error) {
                    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                    //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);                        
                }
            });
```

Comment: ah..i see - i thought about that but wasnt sure...thought the function might just be there for the message or something...thanks for clearing that up...however i am still getting the same error...ill update my code...all i did was change what you said to though...I think.

Comment: I would start with some log in the success, something like user.id  Another thing to try might be to use Parse.User.current() instead of user

Comment: ok...tried this `var html = new EJS({url: 'templates/usershow.ejs'}).render(Parse.User.current());` - same error. what should i put in console.log()? I don't think there is a user.id with parse

Comment: looks like i can use this... http://blog.parse.com/2013/06/04/building-parse-web-apps-with-the-express-web-framework/

Comment: @ewizard Hope you found the solution with the parse blog , however, if you did, make sure you answer your question so someone else can benefit from it in some point!

Comment: i didnt find the answer    going with php mysql